# How can I insert a number at randomized location in matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, random

So I have a 50*50 matrix full of 0's and I'm trying to add two 1's in randomized locations in the matrix. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

We may use `sample` on the sequence of values and assign 1 by specifying `size = 2`

```
m1[sample(seq_along(m1), 2, replace = FALSE)] <- 1
```

-check the location

```
which(m1 == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]  40  47
[2,]  19  50
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(0, 50, 50)
```